# BizTalk Custom Pipeline Component: XmlException crossed a native/managed boundary

Tags: xml, biztalk, pipeline, biztalk-2010

I'm not entirely sure if this exception is anything to do with the custom pipeline component I have created or not.  I have loaded the code in VS2010 and attached to the BTSNTSVC.exe but before I even hit the first break point I get this error:

[image]

There is no disassembly to view and the code (for my component) works fine in a console application with the same input file.

This pipeline component is on a receive port. any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer Jay but as so often happens I walk away from the problem & realise the simple answer to the problem.  Unfortunately I cannot test it out until I get back to work tomorrow but the scenario is one complex xml string in  seven xml documents out BUT they're of different types and I set the receive shape to take messages of the 7 out.  I think what I need to do is set the message type to XmlDocument instead and then cast afterwards in the orchestration.

Answer (score 1):

Add some temporary debugging code to your pipeline component.
Write to the eventlog to show some helpful information to debug with.

Have you turned on tracing in BizTalk to see what the inputs and outputs are?

Answer (score 0):

OK - finally sussed it.  The input was XML as a string from a single field in a table.  However I had saved & formatted (pretty print) as xml & this was the issue.  Reverted it to its original state i.e. all on one line, & it worked :)